# Break from loop after fixed time interval using TCL/expect script

Tags: tcl, expect

I am writing expect script(TCL) and want to break from loop on either of two conditions :
1) After expect -re match
2) After fixed time interval 
1st condition works but 2nd does not work. Any suggestion how to do that?

```
foreach line $commandarray {

send -- $line

sleep 1

send "\r"

while (1) {

  expect -re $currentprompt break

  after 2000 { break }     

send "\x20"

      }

 }
```

Comment: I cannot use timeout as this is a proc. I am calling this proc from the main script and there(main script) I have written the handler for timeout.

Comment: Why do you think a proc disallows `timeout`?

Comment: What happens is: I am providing "set timeout 20" on the second line that is inside the foreach loop. When time out happens it is handled by time out handler written on the main script and the outer foreach also breaks, thus my aim is not achieved.